# Jax-rs Jeresy client gives nul values when I use query params to inject data

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I am just new to JAX-RS. When I Use query params with post request in the client it is returning null values. Here is my code.

Resource WebService Code:

```
@Path("/user")
public class JSONService {

@POST
@Path("/add")

 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addUser(
    @QueryParam("name") String name,
    @QueryParam("age") int age) {

    return Response.status(200).entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age).build();

}
}
```

client code:

```
try {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/simpleweb/rest/user").path("/add");

            MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
              queryParams.add("name", "arunkumar");
              queryParams.add("age", "25");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class,queryParams);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("============getCtoFResponse============");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The OutPut is :

============getCtoFResponse============
addUser is called, name : null, age : 0

Please Help me in this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@FormParam` instead of `@QueryParam`. The latter is for query string key/value pairs that go in the URL, e.g. `/url?name=blah&age=2`. `@FormParam` is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` entity data, which is what you're trying to send

Comment: What type of MediaType i can use if i send as queryparms?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Media type is only for the body. Query param is in the URL, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to use `@QueryParam`, on the client side you would use `webResource.queryParam(String, String)` or `queryParams(MultivaluedMap)`